# Woocommerce hook which runs only on cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need to run a function on only cart page so I need a hook which runs only on cart page. Actually I am reloading saved cart from table when I go to cart page.
I tried to use is_cart() but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used template_redirect hook and within that I check is_cart() which worked for me.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rp_callback' ); 
function rp_callback() {
  if ( is_cart()) {
    //Your code to run on cart when redirect to cart page from anywhere    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call a hook that only runs on the cart page. [Here](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-cart-page/) is one example of a visual guide of possible hooks to call on the cart page - just make sure that you know where the hook is getting called, and that it doesn't interfere with any of the other functions of that cart page.

For example, let's just say you needed your customized function to run at the very top of the cart page, before anything else. In your functions.php file, call something like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart','rplinux_custom_function');

function rplinux_custom_function(){
  //do something amazing here
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show any thing on cart I want to run a function on cart page before cart shows.

Comment: You don't have to display anything - but the hook referenced above will run on the cart page before the cart shows. What is it you are trying to do?